# Is a constant list used in a loop constructed/deleted with each pass?

Tags: python

Will the following snippet create and destroy the list of constants on each loop, incurring whatever (albeit small) overhead this implies, or is the list created once?

```
for i in <some-type-of-iterable>:
    if i in [1,3,5,18,3457,40567]:
        print(i)
```

I am asking about both the Python "standard", such one as exists, and about the common CPython implementation.
I am aware that this example is contrived, as well as that trying to worry about performance using CPython is silly, but I am just curious.

Comment: questions like this are what `dis` is made for!

Comment: Answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example with Python 3.5, list is created *for each iteration*.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def func():
...  for i in iterable:
...   for j in [1,2,3]:
...    print(i+j)
... 
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              54 (to 57)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iterable)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                46 (to 56)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          13 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 53)     
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)        # building list
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             25 BUILD_LIST               3
             28 GET_ITER
        >>   29 FOR_ITER                20 (to 52)    # inner loop body begin
             32 STORE_FAST               1 (j)

  4          35 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             41 LOAD_FAST                1 (j)
             44 BINARY_ADD
             45 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             48 POP_TOP
             49 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           29            # inner loop body end
        >>   52 POP_BLOCK
        >>   53 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7            # outer loop end,
                                              # jumping back before list creation
        >>   56 POP_BLOCK
        >>   57 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             60 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Which list are you saying only gets created once?  I'm no expert on reading python byte-code, but it looks like the inner list (`[4,5,6]`) is going to get built 3 times (once for each `a`) because of the `JUMP_ABSOLUTE 16` which puts you back before the second `SETUP_LOOP`, `BUILD_LIST`, etc...

Comment: I would bet that python2.7 would have the same performance here too... though I'm not sure why they don't optimize that BUILD_LIST away.  I can't think of any way you could possibly get a reference to that list -- I'm guessing that a loop with a "constant" list to iterate over is a rare enough case that it got overlooked?

Comment: An optimizing compiler would hoist the constant expression out of the outer loop.  CPython's compiler does not do such things.  An experienced CPython user who cared would know to do so with `inner_list = [1, 2, 3]` before the for loop, or even better, to use a tuple `(1, 2, 3)`, which would be computed once, at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the python implementation and version and how the "constant lists" are used.  On Cpython2.7.10 with your example, it looks like the answer is that the list in the condition of the `if` statement is only created once...

```
>>> def foo():
...   for i in iterable:
...     if i in [1, 3, 5]:
...       print(i)
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              34 (to 37)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iterable)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                26 (to 36)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          13 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             16 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 3, 5))
             19 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             22 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             28 PRINT_ITEM          
             29 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
             33 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   36 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice:  `16 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 3, 5))`

Python's peephole optimizer has turned our list into a tuple (thanks python!) and stored it as a constant.  Note that the peephole optimizer can only do these transforms on objects if it knows that you as the programmer have absolutely no way of getting a reference to the list (otherwise, you could mutate the list and change the meaning of the code).  As far as I'm aware, they only do this optimization for `list`, `set` literals that are composed of entirely constants and are the RHS of an `in` operator.  There might be other cases that I'm not aware of (`dis.dis` is your friend for finding these optimizations).

I hinted at it above, but you can do the same thing with set-literals in more recent versions of python (in python3.2+, the `set` is converted to a constant `frozenset`).  The benefit there is that `set`/`frozenset` have faster membership testing on average than `list`/`tuple`.